# Prism proper handling of viewmodel collections

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using the prism framework for my Xamarin.Forms application.

This is a common scenario, but it caused me headache.

```
MainPage
 - MainPageViewModel
  - ObserveableCollection<SomePageViewModel>

public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<SomePageViewModel> viewModels;

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        SomePageSelectedCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(NavigateToSomePage);
    }

    public ICommand SomePageSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SomePageViewModel> ViewModels
    {
        get { return viewModels; }
        set { SetProperty(ref viewModels, value); }
    }   

    private async Task NavigateToSomePage(SomePageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var navParams = new NavigationParameters
        {
               {viewModel.typeof(SomePageViewModel).Name, viewModel}
        };
        await Navigation.NavigateAsync(NavigationConstants.SomePageUri, navParams, false);
    }
}

public class SomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected SomeModel someModel;

    public SomePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        someModel = new SomeModel();
        EditCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(Edit);
    }

    public ICommand EditCommand { get; private set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return SomeModel.Name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref SomeModel.Name, value); }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return SomeModel.Description; }
        set { SetProperty(ref SomeModel.Description, value); }
    }   

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ContainsKey(typeof(SomePageViewModel).Name))
        {
            var viewModel = (SomePageViewModel)parameters[typeof(SomePageViewModel).Name];
            Name = viewModel.Name;
            Description = viewModel.Name;
        }       
    }

    private async Task Edit()
    {
        var navParams = new NavigationParameters
        {
            {viewModel.typeof(SomePageViewModel).Name, this}
        };
        await Navigation.NavigateAsync(NavigationConstants.SomePageEditUri, navParams, false);
    }   
}

public class SomePageEditViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public SomePageEditViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        SaveCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(Save);
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    private async Task Save()
    {
        App.ContentService.Save(someModel);
        await Navigation.GoBackAsync();
    }
}
```

So lets navigate from the `MainPage` to a `SomePage`. We want to edit it so we navigate to `SomePageEdit` afterwards and save finally.

What is a proper way to make the changes visible to the SomePage and the MainPage according mvvm/prsim? For the first one I could pass the changes as NavigationParameter into GoBackAsync. But what about the MainPage?

Comment: Can you provide some more context. I assume you are using the NavigationService and navigating with `NavigateAsync` and `GoBackAsync`?

Comment: I provided some pseudo code for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it appears you have a bit of a design problem. To properly architect your app you want something closer to:

## Model

```
public class TodoItem : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private bool _done;
    public bool Done
    {
        get { return _done; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _done, value); }
    }
}
```

## Model Collection Page ViewModel

```
public class TodoItemListPageViewModel : BaseViewModel, INavigationAware
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService { get; }
    public TodoItemListViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        TodoItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<TodoItem>();
        AddTodoItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAddTodoItemCommandExecuted);
        EditTodoItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<TodoItem>(OnEditTodoItemCommandExecuted);
    }

    public ObservableRangeCollection<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; }

    public DelegateCommand AddTodoItemCommand { get; }

    public DelegateCommand<TodoItem> EditTodoItemCommand { get; }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your collection
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if(parameters.GetValue<NavigationMode>(KnownNavigationParameters.NavigationMode) == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            // Option 1
            // Fetch an updated list of TodoItems from your data source
            TodoItems.ReplaceRange(updatedTodoItems);

            // Option 2
            // Replace the updated item or add a new item
        }
    }
```

## Edit Model Page ViewModel

```
    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    private async void OnAddTodoItemCommandExecuted() =>
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("AddTodoItemPage");

    private async void OnEditTodoItemCommandExecuted(TodoItem item) =>
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("EditTodoItemPage", new NavigationParameters { { "item", item } });
}

public class EditTodoItemPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService { get; }
    public EditTodoItemPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSaveCommandExecuted, () => IsNotBusy)
                            .ObservesProperty(() => IsBusy);
    }

    private TodoItem _model;
    public TodoItem Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _model, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Model = parameters.GetValue<TodoItem>("item");
    }

    private async void OnSaveCommandExecuted()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        // Persist any changes

        // Option 1
        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();

        // Option 2
        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(new NavigationParameters { { "updatedItem", Model } });
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

## The Why...

Your ObservableCollection should be `where T : TModel` not `where T : TViewModel`. Another issue you would have immediately is that the `INavigationService` is dependent on knowing what Page you're navigating to/from. So you cannot follow the pattern you're doing there.
Now a couple of notes here.

You'll notice this sample is actually using some helpers from the [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) library. The BaseViewModel class from that library gives you the IsBusy/IsNotBusy property as well as a Title property and the ObservableRangeCollection.

### ObservableRangeCollection vs ObservableCollection

The ObservableRangeCollection gives you a little better performance particularly when working with larger datasets. You may have noticed the Option 1 where we simply get the updated dataset and replace the entire dataset. This is where the ObservableRangeCollection really shines in my opinion since you're able to ensure you have an up to date dataset while minimizing the notifications to the UI resulting in fewer CPU cycles taken up.

### Models, Views, ViewModels

I do not mean for this to an authoritative answer but to at least provide food for thought. From a high level overview of MVVM patterns you generally are working with a View which provides the UX, a ViewModel which provides the business logic for who/what/why/when/where/etc, and a Model which is the data we want to work with. In some cases it can become necessary to introduce a DTO which further abstracts our raw data from the Model we want to work with as a logical unit.

Comment: This makes it clear. I'm pretty new to xamarin and mvvm, and stumbled often over states like to keep the model as plain data object, without any logic/implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.